# Azure table storage exception with no usable stacktrace

Tags: azure, stack-trace, azure-table-storage

I'm getting en error of type System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException:

```
MESSAGE:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
 <code>EntityAlreadyExists</code>
 <message xml:lang="en-US">The specified entity already exists.
RequestId:f1c45274-f149-463e-9815-f9ab9bb075f9
Time:2011-10-05T17:20:32.1930748Z</message>
</error>

STACKTRACE:
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.<HandleBatchResponse>d__1e.MoveNext()
```

My problem is that I cant tell what part of my own code is making the table storage save and causing the error.

Does anyone know how I can get a better stacktrace with some of my own code in it?

Comment: Where did this message come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full details on how to set up Azure diagnostics are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966484.aspx.

In outline, you'll need to configure your application with an Azure trace listener and change your Web role / worker role startup code to copy these messages to table storage. The link gives the boilerplate code.

Once you've done that you should find that any unhandled exception, or indeed anything written out to `System.Diagnostics.Trace`, will appear in your Azure table storage logs.

To read these logs, I use the Cerebrata AzureDiagnosticsManager. There are other tools out there that will do this, including (if you really insist!) Visual Studio itself.